# How can I dynamically set a default value for a WTForms FormField?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Given the following two WTFforms:

```
class NestedForm(FlaskForm):
    note = StringField('Note', validators=[DataRequired()])
    some_id = StringField('Some ID', validators=[DataRequired()])

class Form(FlaskForm):
    id = HiddenField('ID')
    nested_forms = FieldList(
        FormField(NestedForm),
        min_entries=1,
    )
```

How can I dynamically set the value of `some_id`? For instance, from within a Flask view, if a value for `some_id` hasn't been provided.

I have tried setting the value using the following:

```
form.nested_forms[0].some_id = "some_contextual_default_value"
form.nested_form[0].data['some_id'] = "some_contextual_default_value"
```

... which don't seem to do anything. The form validation continues to fail with an error saying that the required field (`some_id`) is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `data` attribute.

```
form.nested_forms[0].some_id.data = "some_contextual_default_value"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. It looks like I was trying to set the value using the field's cached proxy value.